# How can I connect to a database from a celery task using Tortoise-ORM?

Tags: python, docker, celery, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am learning to use celery and I want to be able to do an operation on a database from a Celery task. I am using docker; a container for my app, another for the database (postgresql), and another for celery.

This is the endpoint where I will use my celery task:

```
def random_username():
    username = "".join([random.choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(5)])
    return username

@users_router.get("/transaction_celery/")
async def transaction_celery():
    try:
        async with in_transaction() as connection:
            username = random_username()
            user = User(
                username=f'{username}',
                email=f'{username}@test.com'
            )
            await user.save(using_db=connection)
    except OperationalError:
        pass
    
    print(f'user {user.id} {user.username} is persistent now')
    task_send_welcome_email.apply_async((user.id,))
    return {"message": "done"}
```

And this is my celery task:

```
@shared_task()
def task_send_welcome_email(user_pk):
    from project.users.models import User

    user = User.filter(id=user_pk).first()
    logger.info(f'send email to {user.email} {user.id}')
```

But my task is not working, since in the task it seems I have not logged in to the database (in my application I have already started tortoise with this configuration):

```
def init_db(app: FastAPI) -> None:
    register_tortoise(
        app,
        db_url=settings.DATABASE_URL,
        modules={"models": [
            "project.users.models"
            ]},
        generate_schemas=False,
        add_exception_handlers=True,
    )
```

How can I do operations with my database in the celery task with tortoise-orm?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into an issue where Celery Tasks would fail if they used core functions, normally called from FastAPI endpoint functions, that interacted with the database via Tortoise ORM.  This may not be the same issue, as I'm not using Docker in my project at the moment, but here's what finally worked for me:

`main.py`

```python
from proj import api, create_app

config = config.load_config()

app = create_app()
celery = app.celery_app
[...]

app.include_router(api.views.router)
app.include_router(api.auth.router)
[...]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    uvicorn.run(
        "main:app",
        reload = config.get("keep_alive"),
        host = config.get("host"),
        port = config.get("port"),
        log_config = config.get("log_config"),
        log_level = config.get("uvicorn_log_level"),
        ssl_keyfile = config.get("ssl_keyfile"),
        ssl_certfile = config.get("ssl_certfile")
    )
```

`proj/__init__.py`

```python
from fastapi import FastAPI

from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise

from proj import settings
from proj.utilities.celery import celery_app


def create_app() -> FastAPI:

    app = FastAPI(
        title="Project API",
        description="A project",
        version="0.0.1",
        openapi_tags=settings.api.tags_metadata,
        docs_url="/api"
    )

    # Initialize Tortoise ORM (aka, the database)
    register_tortoise(
        app,
        config = settings.db.TORTOISE_CONFIG,
        generate_schemas = True,
        add_exception_handlers = True
    )

    # Initialize the Celery app
    app.celery_app = celery_app

    return app
```

`proj/settings/__init__.py`

```python
from . import api
from . import celery
from . import db
```

`proj/settings/celery.py`

```python
import os

from functools import lru_cache
from kombu import Queue

from proj import config


config = config.load_config()


def route_task(name, args, kwargs, options, task=None, **kw):

    if ":" in name:
        queue, _ = name.split(":")
        return {"queue": queue}

    return {"queue": "celery"}


class CeleryConfig:
    broker_url: str = config.get("broker_url")
    result_backend: str = f"db+sqlite:///{config.get('database')}"

    task_queues: list = (
        Queue("proj", queue_arguments={"x-max-priority": 10})
    )

    task_routes = (route_task,)


@lru_cache()
def get_settings():

    config_cls_dict = { "proj": CeleryConfig, }
    config_name = os.environ.get("CELERY_CONFIG", "proj")
    config_cls = config_cls_dict[config_name]
    return config_cls()


settings = get_settings()
```

`proj/settings/db.py`

```python
from proj import config


config = config.load_config()

TORTOISE_CONFIG = {
    "connections": {
        # "default": "sqlite://:memory:"
        "default": f"sqlite:{config.get('database')}"
    },
    "apps": {
        "proj": {
            "models": [ "proj.db.models" ],
            "default_connection": "default"
        }
    },
    "use_tz": False,
    "timezone": config.get("timezone")
}
```

`proj/utilities/celery.py`

```python
import asyncio

from celery import current_app as proj_celery_app
from celery.schedules import crontab

from tortoise import Tortoise

from proj import settings
from proj.tasks import task


async def create_celery(celery_app=proj_celery_app):

    celery_app.config_from_object(settings.celery.settings)
    celery_app.conf.update(task_acks_late=True)
    celery_app.conf.update(task_default_priority=5)
    celery_app.conf.update(task_queue_max_priority=10)
    celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
        # Executes daily at midnight.
        "backend_cleanup": {
            "task": "proj:cache_items",
            "schedule": crontab(minute=0, hour=0),
            "args": (),
            "options": {
                "priority": 10,
                "queue": "proj"
            }
        }
    }

    await Tortoise.init(config=settings.db.TORTOISE_CONFIG)

    return celery_app


celery_app = asyncio.run(create_celery(celery_app=proj_celery_app))
```

`proj/tasks/task.py`

```python
import asyncio

from celery import chain, group, shared_task

from proj import core


@shared_task(name="proj:cache_items", bind=True)
def cache_items(sender, **kwargs):

    asyncio.run(core.items.cache())
```

`proj/core/items.py`

```python
import httpx

from proj import config
from proj.db import models
from proj.utilities import common as utility


config = config.load_config()
log = utility.log


async def cache():

    log.debug("Caching items...")

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:

        all_items_response = await client.get(
            url = config.external_api.get("url"),
            headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
        )

    if all_items_response.status_code != 200:
        raise("Failed to get items!")

    all_items = all_items_response.json()
    log.debug(f"Number of items found:  {len(all_items.get('items'))}")

    for item in all_items.get("items"):

        result, result_bool = await models.Items.update_or_create(
            defaults = {
                "type": item.get("item").get("type"),
                "name": item.get("item").get("name")
            },
            item_id = item.get("item").get("id")
        )

    log.debug("All items cached!")
```

`proj/db/models.py`

```python
from tortoise import fields
from tortoise.models import Model


class Items(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    item_id = fields.IntField(unique=True)
    name = fields.CharField(256)
    type = fields.CharField(128)
```

Execute:

`python3 ./main.py`

`python3 -m celery -A main.celery worker --loglevel=debug`

`python3 -m celery -A main.celery beat -s ./Database/db --loglevel=debug`

Running my project like this worked.

In short, adding `await Tortoise.init(config=settings.db.TORTOISE_CONFIG)` to the function that initializes the Celery App (`proj/utilities/celery.py` > `create_celery`) and decorating my Celery Task functions with `@shared_task` allowed everything to work.

Hopefully this will help someone else out there.

(My first contribution back to SO!)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using decorator for inserting db connection in task

```py
import functools
import logging

from src.models.base import session_factory

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def db_session_dec():
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            db_session = session_factory(Config)(expire_on_commit=False)

            try:
                value = func(db_session=db_session, *args, **kwargs)

                return value
            except Exception as e:
                logger.debug("db rollback")
                db_session.rollback()
                logger.exception(e)
            finally:
                logger.debug("db_session closed")
                db_session.close()

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

And in my task definition:

```py
@app.task
@db_session_dec()
def update_monthly(db_session: Session, some_param: str, *args, **kwargs):
    organisations_repo = SAOrganisationsRepo(db_session)

    organisations = organisations_repo.list()
```

And when you call your task pass other parameters directly by keyword, like:

```py
update_monthly.s(some_param="value").apply_async(queue=queue)
```